# Inconsistent cookie setting behaviour

Tags: javascript

So I have the following code to set the javascript cookie in the url [here](http://preview-name-dev.abcd.com/content/diagnostics/us/en/home.html)

```
document.cookie = key + '=' + value + expires + cookieDomain + 
cookiePath + secureCookieFlag;
```

with the following params

```
key : "location-and-language", value : "us|en", expires : "; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2037 00:00:00 GMT", cookieDomain : ";, domain=.name.com", cookiePath : "; path=/", secureCookieFlag : ""
```

Now the issue is, when I run the same code in two different chrome instances

```
1) normal tab : the cookie is set
2) incognito tab : the cookie is not set
```

Requesting anyone to please help me understand why this different behaviour only because of incognito mode?

Comment: When you open an incognito window, it says so right there: `Chrome won’t save the following information: Your browsing history - Cookies and site data - Information entered in forms` It's the whole point of incognito mode.

Comment: Do you mean it is not available _while_ you are browsing in incognito mode, or are you surprised it is gone after you closed the incognito window …? Because for the former, the code you have shown works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of incognito mode is to permit users to navigate without having their history saved in the browser.
That includes visited urls, cookies, site and forms data they possibly gathered or entered.

Comment: Cookies are only deleted when the browser is closed down in incognito mode